# Matroids arising from simplicial complexes

Tags: co.combinatorics

I am somewhat of a newcomer to matroid theory, so I apologize if this is elementary.

Suppose we consider the boundary matrix of a simplicial complex with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. We may consider the binary matroid consisting of the linearly independent sets of columns. Of course for a $1$-dimensional complex, this matroid will be graphic. However, for other higher-dimensional examples it will also turn out to be graphic as well. For example, if we consider the 2-d boundary matrix, $\partial_2$, of a tetrahedron, which happens to be isomorphic as a matroid to $\partial_1$ of a square, (which both happen to be isomorphic to  the uniform matroid $U_{3, 4}$).

Question: What are the known necessary and sufficient topological conditions for a such a matroid arising from the boundary matrix of a simplicial complex to be graphic?

Comment: I found the following paper via google http://arxiv.org/abs/1001.0338 which gives a necessary and sufficient condition for the boundary matrix to be totally unimodular - which may go part of the way towards answering your question.